# Go mod folders not found in Docker

Tags: docker, go, go-modules

I'm very new to go modules and am trying to take a project and update it to use them as they seem like a really great way to finally handle my dependencies. However, I'm having an issue getting things to build in Docker.

I have a project with a `main.go` and a `go.mod` file (which references both private/local repos as well as public ones like `go.uber.org/zap`). I've named my module `github.internal.com/team_name/project_name` I've vendored up my dependencies. So, my project structure looks like:

```
project
- main.go
- internal
  - utils.go
- go.mod (github.internal.com/team_name/project_name)
- vendor
  - go.uber.org
  - private.repo.com
Dockerfile
```

Then, in `main.go` I import

```
import (
    "github.internal.com/team_name/project_name/internal"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
)
```

All of this works great and I can run `go build` no problem.

The issue comes when I try to build using Docker. In my Dockerfile I run

```
ENV GOPATH /go
COPY . /go/src/github.internal.com/team_name/project_name
WORKDIR /go/src/github.internal.com/team_name/project_name
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -o slaxtract main.go
```

When I run `docker build` it returns:

```
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.internal.com/team_name/project_name/internal" in any of:
    /go/src/github.internal.com/project_name/team_name/vendor/github.internal.com/project_name/team_name/internal (vendor tree) 
    /usr/local/go/src/github.internal.com/team_name/project_name/internal (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.internal.com/team_name/project_name/internal (from $GOPATH)
```

How do I get to the right directory to recognize all of my files in my module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all your dependencies are vendored (The vendor directory created by `go mod vendor`) then you need to add the `-mod=vendor` flag to `go build` so it will use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure go has the go modules enabled, you can enforce this by setting the env var `GO111MODULE` to  `on`.

Also as you have vendored your modules dependencies you should build using the `mod=vendor` flag as: `go build -mod=vendor`

Something like `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GO111MODULE=on go build -mod=vendor -a -o slaxtract main.go` should work.